# Passing form parameters to google login (google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm wondering what the best course of action would be for the following problem.

I have an app and users can enter some information in an html form. I want to set something up where users can enter information in the form even before they have created an account.  If they enter information they will be redirected to a login page and then redirected back to the app at the appropriate place (i.e. a page that sends an HTTP POST request, thus saving their info).

OK, I'm doing all of this on Google App Engine and using Google Accounts login. I need a way to pass the parameters from the HTML form to the Google login page and then on to the page that it gets redirected to. I also need to call POST as opposed to GET on the page that users are redirected to. It seems like the default is to make a GET request.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a redirect do a POST; web browsers don't work that way.

The solution would be to have the form POST initially, store the posted data as session data before redirecting to the login page, and fetch the session data after they log in.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you couldn't do a POST from a redirect.